# How to set border-radius to valueBox() in shinyApp?

Tags: r, shinyjs

I want to set **border-radius 20px** for *[image: valueBox()/box()]* in a shinyApp.

I have tried with ccs style to `valueBox()` corners. I used library(shinyjs).

```
valueBox(tag$p("", style = "font-size: 90%;", style = "border-radius: '1em';"), subtitle = div(img(src = "abc.jpg", height = "38", width = "70"), style = "text-align: center;"), width = 3)
```

I expect the `valueBox` should have **round corners** instead of *squared*. But getting

> Error in html: unused arguments (style = "font-size: 90%;", style = "border-radius: '1em';")

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks a lot for your contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sample code for **'border-radius'** :

```
fluidPage(tags$style(".small-box{border-radius: 15px}"),

                            valueBox("123", subtitle = "321", width = 3))
```

Instead of image I placed some text inside the box.

Thanks you.

Comment: To make the ui code look neat, I would suggest you to create a .css file and move the css styles there. Just a suggestion :)